# regex: why does ^.*(\ba\w*\b)?.*$ not capture anything?

Tags: java, regex

The following Java code is intended to capture the word "abc", but instead it gives "null":

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*(\\ba\\w*\\b)?.*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("xxx abc yyy");
if (m.matches()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

If you remove the question mark, it correctly captures "abc". The question mark is greedy, so I would have thought the original code should also give "abc".

Thank you to anyone who can explain why!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.*` at the beginning of your regex is greedy, so it will initially try to match as many characters as possible (the entire string).  As the regex engine moves onto the capturing group, it sees that `\ba\w*\b` cannot match at the end of the string, but because the group is optional it will not backtrack and try to find a match.

To fix this, just change the `.*` at the beginning to `.*?`, which will still match zero or more characters but it will try to match as few as possible (lazy instead of greedy):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*?(\\ba\\w*\\b)?.*$");
```

The other alternative would be to make your capturing group required by removing the `?` after it.  This would force the regex engine to backtrack until the group match is made.  This probably isn't what you want though, as it would change the meaning of the regex (fewer strings would be matched).

**edit:** Looks like I really should have tested this!  As it turns out just changing the `.*` to `.*?` doesn't help here, because your group still can't match at the beginning, and the entire string will be matched by the `.*` at the end (even if you change it to `.*?`).

Your best bet here is to just remove the `?` after the group so that the group is required.  If you still want to match all strings but have the group be null for strings that don't match your group, you could use the following regex:

```
^(?:.*(\ba\w*\b).*|.*)$
```

Comment: I understand the explanation, thank you, but that doesn't seem to work. It still gives null ...

Comment: Switching to a non-greedy `.*?` doesn't help in this case.  It's just trying to match `(\ba\w*\b)`-or-nothing at the beginning of the string now instead of at the end.  Unless the string happens to start with an `a`, group #1 will still be null.

Comment: Thank you. `^(?:.*(\ba\w*\b).*|.*)$` works, like you say. Incidentally I don't understand why `^.*?(\\ba\\w*\\b)?.*?$` (with the last `.*` changed to `.*?`) doesn't work - surely both the `.*?`s are non-greedy and the word starting with a is greedy, so it should capture it.

Comment: @user1310503 The regex matches from left to right, and the backtracking (or forward tracking for lazy expressions) happens from right to left.  In this case, the first `.*?` would match zero characters and then the group would fail to match at the beginning of the string, and then one character at a time the final `.*?` will consume characters until it reaches the end of the string.

Comment: OK, I understand it all at last.

Answer (score 1):

F.J. is correct about the cause.

---

To explicitly match the first word-char sequence starting with `a` on a line, you can match any number of non-word characters or words that start with an ASCII-letter other than `a`, then an optional captured `a` word possibly followed by ignored stuff.

This program, prints `abc` as expected

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^(?:\\W|[b-zA-Z]\\w+)*(?:(a\\w*)?(?:.*))$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("xxx abc yyy");
    if (m.matches()) System.out.println(m.group(1));
  }
}
```

The regex is unambiguous so should only require a single forward pass over the string.  It does require a more careful reading though.

My inclination is these circumstances typically is to explicitly tokenize -- split into words and non-words and then loop over the array looking for what you want.

---

Alternatively, you can use [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) instead of `match` with an unanchored regular expression.

> `find()` Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

So you could do

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\ba\\w*\\b)?");
Matcher m = p.matcher("xxx abc yyy")
while (m.find()) { System.out.println(m.group(1)); }
```

or replace the `while` with an `if` if you only want the first.

---

Finally, `$` doesn't mean end of input in java.  It means end of input or just before a newline at end of input.  The javadoc explains the subtle differences between end anchors:

> `$`  The end of a line
>   `\Z`  The end of the input but for the final terminator, if any
>   `\z`  The end of the input

Comment: Thank you. But what I actually want to use is a much longer regex that checks the whole line and also captures several other bits of text. So I think I want to use matches rather than find. (I didn't know that about $, so that is helpful.)

Comment: Thank you again. Tokenizing may well be a good idea, though my code would become rather long. If there is a simple way to fix my original code (FJ's version doesn't work at present), I would still like to know that.

Comment: @user1310503, I turned my suggested regex into a class and ran it.  It gives me the expected output.  Please see my edit for a class you can copy/paste and let me know if that doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Thanks. It does work as expected. It is just that I want to test the entire line, because it is supposed to contain various other things as well. So I am going to use one based on `^(?:.*(\ba\w*\b).*|.*)$`, but with various other things before the opening parenthesis.